# Usage of Memcache to improve performance of MySQL Query

Tags: mysql, memcached

1. Is is always advantages to use
   memcache to improve performance of
   MySQL query ?
2. Are there any downsides of extensive use of Memcache ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have slow queries the first thing you should address is the query itself as well as your table setup.

Usually altering the query to take advantage of indexes as well as maintaining correct indexes on your tables will actually dramatically reduce the query time of your SQL.  Keeping this down will also allow MySQL to cache queries itself taking the earnest off you.

What is your need to cache your queries external to MySQL itself?

Comment: I am not sure about what I am going to say and it may be wrong so advise if am wrong in what I am thinking.

Comment: I am list of offer ids and for each offer id I am running select query but I am not passing the offer id as hardcoded value into the sql but get in dynamically and so I was under the impression that I cannot use MySQL caching implementation if my value changes dynamically as it needs same query every time(even same bytes structure for the query) and so was thinking of using Memcache for my purpose. Hope I am making some sense here :)

Comment: Try post the query and the table structure here and we may be able to identify indexes you can add to make the query faster removing the need for caching